# How to fix unhandled promise rejection warning in NestJS

Tags: angular, typescript, warnings, backend, nestjs

I'm using NestJS for my backend angular project and I've put method. It was running fine before I install swagger but after I install swagger, I got a warning that saying unhandled promise rejection and it won't allow me to run.

It's working fine If I comment the code in controllers so I think there is a problem with async/await but not really sure how to fix it so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion on how to fix this?

Controller

```
    @Put(':id')
    async updateHelpSubsection(@Body() newHelp: HelpSubsectionModule, @Param() params): Promise<HelpSubsectionModule> {
        try{
            let oldHelpData = await this.helpSubsectionService.getHelpSubsectionbyId(params.id)
            return this.helpSubsectionService.updateHelpSubsection(oldHelpData, newHelp);
        }catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
```

Services

```
    async updateHelpSection(updateHelp: HelpSectionEntity, newHelpData): Promise<HelpSectionEntity> {

        Object.keys(newHelpData).forEach((key) => {
            updateHelp[key] = newHelpData[key];
        });

        try {
            return await this.helpSectionRepo.save(updateHelp);
        } catch (err) {
            throw new HttpException({
                error: err
            }, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
        }
    }
```

This is the warning I'm getting.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update this in the controller:

```
       @Put(':id')
       async updateHelpSubsection(@Body() newHelp: HelpSectionEntity, @Param() params): Promise< HelpSectionEntity> {
           try{
               let oldHelpData = await this.helpSubsectionService.getHelpSubsectionbyId(params.id)
               return this.helpSubsectionService.updateHelpSubsection(oldHelpData, newHelp);
           }catch(e) {
               console.log(e)
           }
       }
```

Modules are not allowed in the types in typescript.

Please replace **HelpSubsectionModule** with **HelpSectionEntity**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeking a way to handle *unhandled errors*, use this way:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) => {
    console.log('handle the error...');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how `@Put(:id)` works, but `updateHelpSection` returns a promise, so you have to handle it with `.then()` to return data if promise resolved  and `catch()` to throw error if promise rejected. Checkout this [article](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/11/09/node-7-and-promise-rejections-please-handle-them/#:%7E:text=DeprecationWarning%3A%20Unhandled%20promise%20rejections%20are,been%20in%20node%20since%206.6.)

Comment: hi by any chance can you pls show me some example how to handle it with my code because I'm still not sure. thanks

Comment: Hi! I recently solved this problem, checkout [this](https://github.com/sometimesvlad/toSpotify-express/blob/master/index.js), for example `app.get('/callback')` method, here i use async function `getToken` which returns promise, so we need to call `then()` and `catch()` to handle returned promise's resolve or reject => no errors. Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

what you see is just a warning of good practices.

Each Promise must have a method to catch the errors that will be generated when making the request

For example:

This is the promise.

```
const slowAndSteady = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    reject();
});
```

if you use async/await like this.

```
(async function() {
    await slowAndSteady();
})();
```

you get the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning, but if you used in this way.

```
slowAndSteady
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log('result', result);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('error: ', err);
    });
```

the warning disappears.

But if you still needed use the async/await you have two options.

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const result = await slowAndSteady();
    console.log('result', result);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('Error caught',e);
  }
})();
```

Or

```
(async () => {
  const result = await slowAndSteady().catch((e) => console.log('Error caught',e));
  console.log('result', result);
})();
```